# Waves and Newton's Third Law

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, waves

I'm a really newbie in Physics trying to understand a bit about waves.

Firstly, i'm using the Wikipedia's definition of wave , that is, as energy traveling through a medium/space without permanent alteration of one of its properties ( or parameter ).

Intuitively, i'm seeing a wave as simply the propagation of the variation of a parameter of a part of an entity ( variation of the  magnetic field  of a point in the space, variation of the height of a mass in the string, variation of a mass in the ocean ,  variation of the pressure of a mass in the air  ) to all other parts of that entity .The propagation would happen because the parts of the entity ( the space without matter, the string, the ocean, the air ) are somehow tied ( by electromagnetic field,  by virtual springs representing the interactions between molecules of a string, ocean, air ).   Being tied, it's natural to see the variation of the parameter of one part of that entity is automatically causing the parameter of the other parts of that entity to vary.

I was discussing with someone about waves and he mentioned the job of the Newton's Third Law in the propagation of a wave but now i'm thinking ... Could waves exist in a world withouth Newton's Third Law ( action causing reaction )?.   In another words, could the variation of the parameter of a part of an entity still be propagated to the other parts of the entity withouth the action-reaction law?  Could the variation of the parameter of a part of an entity make the parameter of a part next to it vary withouth suffering any influence ( in the value of the mentioned parameter ) from that point.
I guess the first and second Newton's laws would still be necessary, right?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: What connection you see between waves and 3rd law of mechanics? Be more explicit. It's first of all the 1st law of mechanics, conservation of linear momentum which is passes from one point in the medium to a neighbor one. With e.m. waves it can be regarded as flux ~ ExM, that passes from one point to the other.

Comment: That's the point ... I don't see any connection. So is the answer, yes ? Waves could exist in a world withouth Newton's Third Law.

Comment: To this I can't answer. Without the 3rd law all sort of phenomena in our world would go differently, (stars would collapse because lower layers in their body won't be able to sustain the upper layers). But what I said is that the wave-propagation is the direct consequence of the 1st law.

Comment: Waves are nature's expression of the flow of energy through space and time. The conservation of this energy connects waves to the third law.

Comment: The 3rd law of mechanics is a low of statics, and has nothing to do with energy conservation. Whenever a system is static, the sum of the forces is zero. Which energy conservation? Where do you see in the question a requirement of static equilibrium?

Answer (score 5):

The answer is no. The reason is that waves are the solution of the wave equation, and the wave equation cannot be derived withouth implicitly assuming Newton's third law. It is intuitive to see why in waves that propagate in a medium. For instance, the bouncing back could be up and down in a transversal wave (for instance, the atoms of a string) or back and forth (for instance, the air molecules in sound) in a longitudinal wave. In both cases the elements of the medium   need  to "bounce back", or be "kept in place" by either the next or the previous element, otherwise   the elements would propagate themselves and that would not be a wave. For details on the derivation of the wave equation you can read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_equation#Derivation_of_the_wave_equation).
For a wave that propagates in the vacuum, such as an electromagnetic wave, I do not have an intuitive explanation at hand yet.

Comment: I deleted some comments because they were obsolete, but some of them were also close to being inappropriate, so let me remind everyone involved to keep a level head when you're on this site.

Comment: @DavidZ did I? I was completely unaware of that. Actually after you warning acouple of days ago I had put a stronger effort not to respond to provocations.

Comment: A little bit, yeah. Nothing too bad here, though, I just wanted to insert a reminder so that the comment discussion didn't escalate into a big argument in the future. (I've seen it happen.) If you want clarification on where we draw the line between appropriate and inappropriate, feel free to ask in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71).